# If I let Startup Repair complete in windows, will it affect my ubuntu installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot

I am on dual boot, ubuntu and windows.

I was playing a game last night when the laptop overheated and rebooted itself. Now windows wouldn't load. Thankfully, the ubuntu side is still ok.

- If I run "startup repair" on windows, will it affect the ubuntu side?
- Will it access my files on ubuntu and modify things without my knowledge?
- Or will it just modify the windows files?

I don't want to reformat as much as possible as I don't have the windows disk with me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will modify both the system files it uses to boot on C:/ and the master boot record, so it's possible that you can't boot into Ubuntu afterwards. In that case just reinstall the bootloader (e. g. Grub). The files on the Ubuntu partition will remain untouched.